# Populate Model from a Query with a One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldbox

I have two tables:

```
surveyTemplateHeader
surveyTemplateQuestions
```

What I was looking to do was get the information from both tables:

```
var q = dao.getSurveyTemplateDetails( surveyTemplateID = ARGUMENTS.surveyTemplateID );
```

Then use Coldbox to populate my model, `surveyTemplate`, with the query data:

```
var surveyTemplateObj = populator.populateFromQuery( beanFactory.getInstance("surveyTemplate"), q );
```

This works, **however**, the model is only populated with **one** question.  The surveyTemplate I am testing has **three** questions.

I have tried to set up a `property name` correctly in my model to use `fieldtype="one-to-many"` but that does not appear to have made a difference.

```
property name="surveyTemplateQuestionID" fieldtype="one-to-many";
```

While Coldbox's documentation for models overall is quite good, I am not able to find an answer for this, which probably means I am off track a good bit in my implementation of this.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, what I did for this is I injected a `surveyTemplateQuestions` model into my `surveyTemplate` model:

```
property name="surveyTemplateQuestions" inject="surveyTemplateQuestions";
```

then I set the `surveyTemplateQuestions` property with the questions query:

```
surveyTemplateObj.setSurveyTemplateQuestions(qQuestions);
```

Not exactly what I was looking for but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over query to build Arrays of objects. populateFromQuery method takes query row-number to get data from query.

```
var surveyTemplateObj = [];

for(var row in q){
    ArrayAppend(surveyTemplateObj, populator.populateFromQuery( beanFactory.getInstance("surveyTemplate"), q , row.currentRow));
}
```

API Doc info
http://apidocs.ortussolutions.com/coldbox/4.3.0/coldbox/system/core/dynamic/BeanPopulator.html#populateFromQuery()

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sana.  I am actually doing this in another part of the code for the Survey Template listing page.  The difference there is I only need the information in the header table.  I am wanting to have an object represent a complete survey template, with all of its questions as well.  If I were to loop over the query and create an array of question objects, would I be able to "merge" that somehow into the template object with the header information?  Thanks!